# Excluding web links with specific extensions in web scraper

Tags: python, regex, pdf

I need to exclude printing links in my web scraper that end in .od .jpg .pdf or .mp3

Here's my `if` statement

```
if link in linkList():
      print link
```

Is there some library in Python for that? I only know of"RegEx" but I'm not the greatest user of it.

Comment: Do you even have the rest of the scrapper code? Sounds like a "do it for me" QA.

Comment: that could be a solution, but what if I have several endings for check out? Then I would need some list or something right? I can not simply write `link.endswith('.pdf','.jpg','.mp3')` or I can?

Comment: @KurzedMetal, I have of course, it has 400 lines of code so I don't wanna bother with rest of it, I have a issue and question only for that so I don't see a problem

Comment: Yes, you can use a tuple to provide multiple suffixes to `endswith` ([endswith doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith))

Comment: @dzordz You in fact can. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your link is just the path, you can do something like the following:

```
import os
if os.path.splitext(link)[1] not in ['.jpg', '.pdf', '.mp3']:
    print link
```

The function `splitext` takes a path and returns a tuple containing the path without the extension, followed by the extension. For example:

```
>>> os.path.splitext('http://www.example.com/path/to/filename.ext')
('http://www.example.com/path/to/filename', '.ext')
```

So if you split the link with that function, you can check whether the last element of the tuple is a member of another list/set/tuple containing your blacklist of extensions.

Comment: @OlehPrypin I don't see anyone posting an answer with `endswith`... yet.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way. The `os.path.splitext` solution is probably better, but to just see if a string ends in one of many substrings:

```
if link.endswith((".pdf", ".mp3", ".jpg")):
    print link
```